# Finite-dimensional Banach algebras with non-dense invertible groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

It is easy to see that for any finite $n$, the invertible elements in the algebras algebras $\mathbb{C}^n$ (edowed with the maximum norm, say) and $M_n$ (all square matrices) are dense. Thus, by the Artin-Wedderburn all finite-dimensional C*-algebras have dense invertible groups.

> Is there an example of a unital, finite-dimensional Banach algebra where the invertible elements are **not** dense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The spectrum of a non-invertible element is finite. So you can find sequence of numbers in the resolvent set converging to zero. From this, you can cook up a sequence of invertible elements converging to your non-invertible element.

Comment: What if the algebra is real?

Comment: The spectrum of an element of a real algebra equals the spectrum in the complexification. You can choose the sequence to be made of real numbers.

Comment: If $a \in A$ has finite spectrum (wit $A$ real or complex), then there is a very small $\epsilon > 0$ with $0 \notin \sigma(a + \epsilon)$.